# How to find integer solutions for an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pythagorean Triplets with “Bounds”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179997/pythagorean-triplets-with-bounds)

I typed following equations in into Wolfram Alpha -

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2\\
a+b+c=1000
$$

It showed me multiple possible integer solutions and also shows the total number of integer solutions.

How is this done? Could I calculate total number of solutions without actually solving for all those solutions?

Comment: Just found : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179997/pythagorean-triplets-with-bounds

Answer (score 4):

Using [Euclid's formula for generating Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple), we can take $a,b,c$ to be $p^2-q^2,p^2+q^2,2pq$ where $p,q,r$ are integers.

So, $$p^2-q^2+p^2+q^2+2pq=1000\implies p(p+q)=500$$

So $p+q=\frac{500}p$ which must be some integer.

If $p=1,p+q=500\implies q=499$ and so on